# Is SSO in Coldfusion 2021 a Standard or Enterprise only feature?

Tags: coldfusion, single-sign-on, saml

I have tried for a week to get an answer to this out of Adobe, but nobody seems to know the answer and I'm running out of time.  I'm currently running an SSO SAML implementation for a client but the ColdFusion box is running in Adobe's "*Try it*" mode, which is basically Enterprise mode.  As soon as I enter my license key it is going to revert back to Standard mode.  My question is, will all the new SSO/SAML functionality that Adobe added to CF v2021 continue to work in Standard mode, or is that an Enterprise mode feature.

I have Googled until my fingertips bled.  The answer is nowhere on the CF site, nor can the front-line support people answer it.  Each call takes over 30 minutes of hold time to reach anyone and so far nobody can answer for sure.  Our high-availability and secure HIPAA environment makes it too difficult to just try it and "un-do it" if we are wrong.

Does anyone know for sure if SSO is an Standard feature or not?

Comment: I do NOT know for certain, but FWIW the FAQ's page links to:  https://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-enterprise/buying-guide.html which lists SSO under "ColdFusion Standard (2021 Release)".  Agreed, there should be a more definitive feature comparison ....

Comment: Hmm, that's the best reference I've seen so far.  I probably missed it searching for "SSO" and "SAML".

Comment: It's probably correct, but a confirm from someone actually using Standard and SSO would be nice. Given the lack of *comprehensive* Standard vs Enterprise feature lists over the years, a single link doesn't exactly fill me with confidence (-;

Answer (score 1):

According to this [feature matrix](https://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-enterprise/buying-guide.html), showing the difference between standard editions of 2016, 2018, and 2021, SSO is supported in Standard Mode.